# Returned document lacks signature

Tags: docusignapi

I'm performing a DocuSign integration with a FileMaker solution to send signature requests via email, and receive a copy of the signed document once completed. I'm using the Java SDK to email signature request, as well as a Javalin app process to listen for the completed signature event, as well as more Java to pull the document back into FileMaker.

When the completed document is sent to my listener and pulled in, the document lacks a signature and tab field. It essentially looks just like the pdf document before being sent.

I have a feeling there's a variable I can tweak in some object to allow the signature to appear after being signed. I've played with all the usual suspects (e.g., eventNotification.setIncludeDocumentFields("true")), but nothing seems to do the trick. Any hints?

Aside from looking through the code for every object I'm instantiating and trying different variations, it's hard to pinpoint the exact source of failure in this. Thanks for any leads!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're receiving notifications by either including the `eventNotification` object in your Envelopes::create call or are using Connect at the account level. Either way, that's great, that's exactly right.

You can request notifications at many different points along the processing route of the envelope. To receive signed documents, you'll want the notification when the **envelope is completed**. At that point all signer recipients have signed.

To receive the notification when the envelope is **complete**, either adjust your Envelope Send parameters (the `eventNotification` value) or the settings for Connect (via the Admin tool), whichever one you're using.